# How to redirect ant to use java from jdk in /usr instead from jre in /opt?

Tags: java, jdk, update-alternatives

I have followed a blog set up jre on my machine in `/opt/` directory. Then I redirected firefox to use `libnpjp2.so` from `/opt/java/64/jre1.8.0_73/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so`.

Now I have to install another program and the setup for this program requires me to run `ant`. But the output of ant turns out to be:

`Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /opt/java/64/jre1.8.0_73/lib/tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed`

And the output of `update-alternatives --get-selections | grep ^java` is

`java                           manual   /opt/java/64/jre1.8.0_73/bin/java
javac                          auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
javadoc                        auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javadoc
javah                          auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javah
javap                          auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javap`

I think I have to point the first `java` mentioned `manual` to use jdk from `/usr` directory.

Kindly guide me what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and input the desired selection number according to the `Selection` column.

Do the same for others (if you want) e.g. `javah`, `javap`.

Comment: I worked like a charm. I have just one last question.

Will my `jre` and the linked library files for mozilla will work without any problem?

Comment: @nainometer Check, if not then make a symlink of `/opt/java/64/jre1.8.0_73/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so` on where desired in `/usr`..should work fine..